# refresh div in web page with data from database

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a a div on a page that randomizes data (picture and text) from a MySQL database and displays it.  Basically, every time you hit refresh it shows a different picture and text. Is it possible to put a button does the exact same thing, without having to refresh the whole page?

Comment: Yes, that's what Ajax is for.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `$.ajax()` and `$.html()`.

Hook up a jQuery `$.ajax()` to your button via `$.click()`.  Then for the data that comes back, set the `div`'s content with `$.html()`.

Post some code, and I'll give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little complex for what you're trying to do.  But with this you could send back more than one image as JSON and have your success function loop through them, etc.

The jQuery ajax post:

```
$("#yourbutton").click(function(e){ //when your button is clicked
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // or POST
    url: 'ajax/testajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'getimage' : '1'}, // just post a 1 because you're getting a random image anyway
    success: function(response) {
        var obj = eval(response);
        var image = obj[i];
        var newPic = $('<img/>',{ //new img with the following attributes
            src: image.src,
            name: image.name,
            width: '100' //and other attributes you want to include
        });
        newPic.appendTo("#container"); //apendd the new image to the container  
    }
});
});
```

The php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['getimage'])){

    if($_POST['getimage'] == 1){

         // do your query for the random image

        $img = array(
            array("name" => $row['imageName'], "src" => $row['imageSrc'])
        );
        echo json_encode($img);  //send back as JSON

    } else {

        echo 'fail';  // send back a failure

    }
}
```